# How many graphs is there, with 5 vertices and 3 edges of maximum degree 3?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How many graphs is there, with 5 vertices and 3 edges of maximum degree 3?

I don't know if that graph even exist?

Comment: If there are only three edges the maximum degree of any vertex can't possibly be _higher_ than three regardless.  But there are plenty of graphs that meet your criterion; for instance, the graph on {1,2,3,4,5} with edges (1-2), (2-3), (3-4) (and 5 as an isolated vertex).  Can you be more specific/clearer about your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume that the vertices are labeled.

There are $\dbinom{5}{2}=10$ possible edges. We want to pick three, so there are $\dbinom{10}{3}=120$ such graphs.

If the vertices aren't labeled, then there are only 4 configurations. Specifically, the edges can only assume the following configurations:
 /\  |, /|/, _|_, or a triangle.

Comment: thank you for explanation. but what those configurations (lines) mean?

Comment: Your list of possible configurations isn't correct.  The first requires three six vertices, some of them have fewer than three edges, and you're missing the path \/\ (if I've understood your notation).

Comment: and do we include loops in possible edges? so if one verticle has one loop and two edges?

Comment: My apologies. I have fixed the notation, and the mistake.